# Perform actions on a certain window of the application with AppleScript

Tags: xcode, applescript, nswindow

I'm building a macOS app for managing locations sent to an iOS device via GPX file in Debug mode, so I need to have to Xcode windows opened for each project. I got an AppleScript which presses  Debug -> Simulate Location -> "my gpx file name" for continuous location updates. However, it works only if the window with an iOS project (through which I simulate the location) is frontmost.

I want the script to be able to perform said actions just on a window with a certain name (or rather whose name contains ...), no matter of the hierarchy. I don't want it to be brought to the front or activated, as I might be coding something in a second one while the script runs.

I tried many ways, but with my limited understanding of AppleScript I either get an error (like "Can't locate menu item 1 in bla-bla-bla of the process Xcode) or the window activates and doesn't work in the "background".

```
repeat while true
    tell application "System Events" to tell process "Xcode"
        click menu item "MyLocation" of menu 1 of menu item "Simulate Location" of menu 1 of menu bar item "Debug" of menu bar 1
    end tell
    delay 0.2
end repeat
```

Is it even possible to perform any action on inactive window? I thought it is since the system lets you scroll without focusing the window.

Comment: Afaik it's not possible to achieve this with c/objc/swift, as the apps you build are sandboxed. Probably a way around would be to call AppleScript from the app, but I couldn't do it, the script just did not work. As for AppleScript capabilities, it certainly is able to select a specific Application and iterate over its open windows, make some an active one and simulate mouse/keyboard events.

Comment: Sure, you can iterate over windows with AppleScript and make one of them the frontmost - but what I was saying is that you cannot use AppleScript to send mouse and keyboard events to an application that _isn't_ frontmost, i.e. to a background application.

Comment: Ah, I see, thank you. Moreover, I found out that I can't use a menu bar of an unfocused window, as windows don't "own" menu bars. So I guess what I wanted is impossible with AppleScript